# Batch edit activities in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I have recently decided to add a Navigation Drawer to every screen in my app. I already have the working code. Is there a faster way to add the same layout to every screen or must I do this manually?

Comment: You should add more info to this question to make it more clear. You're basically just asking for a "Yes" or "No" answer here. It would be better if you posted some code of how you're doing it now so others can compare and see if they have a better way for you to do it. As of right now, no one knows how you're implementing it, so how would we know if there is a faster way?

Comment: You could extend a base activity in each case so that the navigation drawer code is centralized, and then ask each subclass for the content view. However, in its current form this question is too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do it is to create an `Activity` or `Fragment` class say `BaseActivity` that all your `Activity` or `Fragment` will inherit, and put your Navigation Drawer logic there.

Comment: Definitely. If you find you're repeating code across numerous classes, consider using abstraction.